# strpbrk function - C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to break a string from the occurrence of the given character. I am using the strpbrk function. But I get this error

```
21 G:\My Programs\C\horse.cpp invalid conversion from `char' to `const char*'
```

The code which I used is as follows

```
char horses[100], h[1];

 char *brokenstring;

 h[0] = 'H';

 brokenstring = strpbrk (horses,h[0]);
```

I get this error in the line where I use the strpbrk function. Please help me out.

Comment: 1) What's the point of a char array of size 1 here? 2) Were you looking for `strchr()`?

Comment: I think this code must be incomplete, you never initialize horses.

Comment: char *strpbrk(const char *, const char *)

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a const char * to strpbrk()'s 2nd argument and also you need to terminate the string with null.

```
int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {    

 char horses[100], h[2];
 char *brokenstring;

 h[0] = 'H';
 h[1]=0;   
 brokenstring = strpbrk (horses,h);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: the conversion from unqualified type to qualified type is made automatically. gcc generates a warning, but it is not necessary to qualify it.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to strpbrk must be a string, not a char.

It is not clear what you want to do; are you sure you don't need, e.g., strtok()?

strpbrk() is useful if you have several possible dividing characters (e.g. H, Y and K -- then you pass "HYK"). Otherwise you'll be better served by strchr().

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strpbrk/ I see that the function looks like this

```
char * strpbrk ( const char *, const char * );
```

But you are passing it horses and `h[0]`. `h[0]` is not a `char *`, it is actually a `char`. If you just passed it `h` you would be OK.

Edit: as others have said, you actually would need to make sure you null terminated h.